# Vim Fold Expression Not Working

Tags: vim, folding

I've implemented a pretty simple fold expression for *Markdown*, but it doesn't work for some reason. I've inserted some `echom` messages into the `FoldExpr` function and I can see them in the messages and they are correct. So it seems to be applied, but no folds are there. Apart from the fact I set `foldlevel` to zero, `zM` also have no effect.

Does anyone see the failure?

`ftplugin/markdown_fold.vim :`

```
" Generate the folds text for the `foldtext` option.
" Simply use the first line (which should contain the header)
" and extend it by the number of lines in this section.
"
function! FoldText()
  let l:title = getline(v:foldstart)
  let l:line_count = (v:foldend - v:foldstart)
  let l:line_text = l:line_count > 1 ? 'lines' : 'line'
  let l:text = l:title . ' [' . l:line_count . ' ' . l:line_text . ']'
  return l:text
endfunction

" Return the fold level for the `foldexpr` option.
" Checks if the current line is a header.
" The level is equal to the number of hashes of the header.
" All lines which are not a header have the same level as their predecessor.
"
function! FoldExpr()
  let l:line = getline(v:lnum)
  let l:count = len(matchstr(l:line, '^#\+'))

  if l:count > 0
    return '>0'
  else
    return '='
  endif
endfunction


" Use custom fold expression and text.
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=FoldExpr()
setlocal foldtext=FoldText()

" Fold everything per default.
setlocal foldlevel=0
setlocal foldminlines=0
```

Comment: you are effectively always return either `>0` or `=`, which comes down to all lines will be on foldlevel 1. I think you should probably use `return '>'.l:count`

Comment: Okay. What I don&#39;t want, is to have section 3 fold within section 2 and so on. So actually all content in folded by level 1 and the headers remain as the fold text.

Comment: Ah, I see the error. I was wrong. There is no such thing as a foldlevel 0, foldlevel 0 means, the line is not in a fold. And you are always returning 0 effectively meaning each line is not folded. If you make `return '>1'` it should work

Comment: I read again the fold-expr documentation and that makes sense... Works now. Extended it a bit. Thanks! Would u like to write an answer, so I can mark it as the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

That `>0` doesn't make sense. Unfortunately, Vim accepts it without complaining. According to [`:help fold-expr`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold-expr), a fold value of `0` means *the line is not in a fold*. To start a first-level fold, return `>1` instead.